# Multiply Numpy arrays of different sizes

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of coefficients and a list of times

```
a = np.array([0,1,2,3])
t = np.array([1,2,3])
```

I would like to perform some multiplicative operation on the two where each coefficient is multiplied by each of the times to result in an array like:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

I can do this with a for loop like:

```
np.array([i * t for i in a])
```

However I was wondering whether there was a more efficient numpythonic way of performing this operation without the for loop as in reality I have much bigger arrays and multiple sets of coefficients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (uses broadcasting).

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> t = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> res1 = t * a[:, None]
>>> res1
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Comment: Ah yes, that looks good, do you know what the difference would be between a[:, None] and a[:, np.newaxis]? In terms of speed?

Comment: I think they are same. `None` is just an alias for `np.newaxis`. It is mentioned here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis

Answer (score 0):

My prefered way is:

```
a[:, None] * t
```

But there is also a special method for that:

```
np.outer(a, t)
```